# Connection pool with javax MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Is there any way to make a Connection pool using this only:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html ?

In tomcat7 and MySQL i have a lot of problems with DBCP driver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't. You could implement your own ConnectionPool but this is a realy bad idea.

My suggestion is to use some 3rd party library like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/). It is very easy to use.

[c3p0 example](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#quickstart)

Other ConnectionPool Libraries:

- [JavaXT Connection Pool](http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/sql/ConnectionPool)
- [Proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/)
- [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) + [howto](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2013/01/30/Using-Tomcat-JDBC-connection-pool-in-a-standalone-environment)
- [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/)

Comment: followed c3p0 example for mysql, failed as DBCP did, throwing this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.ser.Indirector  i think ill give up on those damn libraries, there is no f"ing way retarded tomcat7 uses them

Comment: @Alpha2k your issue is half-done. you need to add  m2change commons library here: https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/issues/480#issuecomment-58468037

Comment: ok done, getting more errors com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.

Comment: nvm dude thanks for your time, got it solved, went to wrong database, instead of testjava went to javatest rofl... c3p0 ftw, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to write your own Connection Pool Manager by providing your own implementations of the interfaces listed in the interfaces section.
"The connection pool manager, a facility in the middle tier of a three-tier architecture, uses these classes and interfaces behind the scenes. "

In practice, why? perhaps you need to explain your statement "In tomcat7 and MySQL i have a lot of problems with DBCP driver. " because that is leading you down a rabbit hole of duplicated effort.